# First order differential equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A car is travelling at $100$ km/h on a level road when it runs out of fuel. Its speed $v$ (in km/h) starts
> to decrease according to the formula $$\frac{dv}{dt}=-kv \quad (1)$$ where $k$ is constant. One kilometre after running out of fuel its speed has fallen to $50$ km/h. Use the chain rule substitution $$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{dv}{ds}v$$ to solve the differential equation.

(Note: Although I haven't solved it yet, the answers say that this isn't a reasonable model as the velocity is always positive; I didn't make a typo in the question.)

What I'm trying to do is solve velocity as a function of displacement ($s$, in km), velocity as a function of time ($t$, in hours), and displacement as a function of time (I need these functions for later parts of the question).

So far I've found velocity as a function of displacement ($v(s)$):
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-k\frac{ds}{dt} \quad \text{(from (1))}$$
$$\int \frac{dv}{dt} dt = -k \int \frac{ds}{dt} dt $$
$$v(s) = -ks+C$$
$$v(0) = 100 \implies C=100, \ v(1)=50 \implies k=50$$
$$v(s) = -50s+100$$
Then I've tried to find velocity as a function of time ($v(t)$), but I've got stuck. I can't find any differential equation I can use to get this, or to get displacement as a function of time ($s(t)$).

The answer key says $v(t)=100e^{-50t}$ and $s(t)=2(1-e^{-50t})$.

I've solved such questions many times before, but it's been a while so I'm a bit rusty. So, even a hint might be enough for me to realise what to do.

Thanks

Comment: The general solution to $\frac{dy}{dt} = cy$ ($c$ a constant) is given by $y(t) = a\cdot e^{ct}$ with a constant $a$ which is determined by adding an initial condition like $y(0) = 100$. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath Ah yes! I'd forgotten this basic fact due to how long it's been since I've worked with differential equations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find $v(t)$ using amsmath's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214591/first-order-differential-equation-question#comment8747587_4214591), and that $k=50$:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-kt=-50t$$
$$v(t)=Ae^{-50t},\ \text{for some constant $A$}$$
$$v(0)=100\implies A=100$$
$$v(t)=100e^{-50t}$$
We can find $s(t)$ using $\frac{ds}{dt}$ and the chain rule, however I'm not sure if this is the most efficient method. We know from $v(s)$ that $\frac{dv}{ds}=-50$, so $\frac{ds}{dv}=-\frac{1}{50}$. We can also see from $v(t)$ that $\frac{dv}{dt}=-5000e^{-50t}$.
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{ds}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{1}{50}\times-5000e^{-50t}=100e^{-50t}$$
$$\int \frac{ds}{dt} dt = 100\int e^{-50t}dt$$
$$s(t) =100\times-\frac{1}{50}e^{-50t}+C$$
$$s(t)=-2e^{-50t}+C$$
$$s(0)=0 \implies C=2$$
$$s(t)=-2e^{-50t}+2=2(1-e^{-50t})$$